# Formating of var data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var in jquery which contains values like this ..

```
var data = [["Local", 75], ["STD", 55], ["ISD", 96], ["VOIP", 123], ["INCOMING", 34], ["INET", 104]];
```

Now i have another var which contains values like ..

```
var data2=["LOCAL,200","STD,120","ISD,200","VOIP,500","INCOMING,234","INET,104"]
```

So my question is how can i convert `var data2` to `var data` because ,my application needs the data in the `var data` format.

Please help .

Comment: Do  you have any attempts? your own code?

Comment: @MyP3uK i tried to do it from server side code ,but no success

Comment: @Siddhu: Can you show what you've tried?

Answer (score 5):

This'll do it:

```
var data2=["LOCAL,200","STD,120","ISD,200","VOIP,500","INCOMING,234","INET,104"]
data = data2.map(function(e){return e.split(',')});
```

result:

```
data === [["LOCAL","200"], ["STD","120"], ["ISD","200"],
          ["VOIP","500"], ["INCOMING","234"], ["INET","104"]]
```

---

Or, if the 2nd item in the "sub-arrays" **has**  to be a integer:

```
data = data2.map(function(e){
    var temp = e.split(',');
    temp[1] = parseInt(temp[1], 10);
    return temp;
});
```

result:

```
data === [["LOCAL",200], ["STD",120], ["ISD",200],
          ["VOIP",500], ["INCOMING",234], ["INET",104]]
```

---

However, possibly the best solution would be to form it into a object like this:

```
data = data2.reduce(function(obj, current){
    var temp = current.split(',');
    obj[temp[0]] = parseInt(temp[1], 10)
    return obj;
}, {});
```

result:

```
data === {"LOCAL":200, "STD":120, "ISD":200,
          "VOIP":500, "INCOMING":234, "INET":104};
```

Comment: @Siddhu: Are you sure `data2` is an array? What does `console.log(data2 instanceof Array)` say?

Comment: console.log(data2 instanceof Array) says **false**

Comment: I thought as much. How is `data2` being set? Can you edit that into your question?

Comment: Sir can i define data2 as array ?

Comment: @Siddhu: That's exactly what we need, `data2` defined as an array.

Comment: @Siddhu: What browser are you using?  `Array.prototype.map` only exists in "modern" browsers (meaning not IE < 9).